# Does Spring support OpenJDK 12

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are planning to migrate our application from Oracle JDK 8 to OpenJDK 12. Currently we are using Spring Boot version *1.4.5.RELEASE*.

I have read many articles saying that from Spring Boot 2.2.X, we will have support for OpenJDK 12. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: JDK 11 is fully supported, things are tested with JDK12 afaik. But do you really want to go to 12 (13 is up an coming already). Why not just 11 (the LTS version).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Spring Framework Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions) (as per the August 2020 update)

> JDK Version Range
>
> ---
>
> - Spring Framework 5.3.x: JDK 8-17 (expected)
> - Spring Framework 5.2.x: JDK 8-15 (expected)
> - Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
> - Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10
> - Spring Framework 4.3.x: JDK 6-8
>
> We fully test and support Spring on Long-Term Support (LTS) releases of the JDK, i.e. currently JDK 8 and 11 (both with a lifetime until 2023) and expecting JDK 17 (to be released in late 2021). Additionally, there is support for intermediate releases such as JDK 9/10/12/13/14 and the upcoming JDK 15/16 on a best-effort basis, meaning that we accept bug reports and will try to address them as far as technically possible but won't provide any service level guarantees.
>
> *Please upgrade to Spring Framework 5.1+ (and the corresponding Spring Boot 2.1+) for JDK 11+ support, as the common Long-Term Support migration path from JDK 8. No earlier Spring versions are officially supported on JDK 11, in particular not with JDK 11 bytecode level. Note that third-party components might not fully support JDK 11 yet, so you are likely to be limited in your full-stack options.*

<sup>The above Wiki page is updated regularly, and you are advised to check it yourself.</sup>

---

If you switched to Spring 5.1.x, you will be OK on Java 12.

As for Spring Boot, 2.1 is good for Java 11.  Spring Boot 2.2 supports up to Java 13.

(You can look up the versions of Java supported for a given Spring Boot release by looking at the "Getting Started" page of its reference documentation.)